# Seidel method in Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, linear-equation

I need to implement Seidel method in Pascal. I tried this code but it gives the wrong answer. I don't understand what the mistake is. This is what the procedure for finding roots looks like:

```
procedure Seidel(n: Integer; var x: vector; a: matrix; e: Real);
var k, i, j, z: integer;
s: Real;
begin
  for k := 1 to 100 do
    begin
      z := k;
      for i := 1 to n do
        begin
          s := a[i, n + 1];
          for j := 1 to n do s := s - a[i, j] * x[j];
          s := s / a[i, i];
          x[i] := x[i] + s;
          if abs(s) > e then z := 0
        end;
      if z <> 0 then Break;
    end;
end;
```

Procedure for variable 'a'

```
procedure ReadA;
var i, j: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to m do
    for j := 1 to m + 1 do
      a[i, j] := StrToFloat(Form1.StringGrid1.Cells[j, i])
end;
```

This is how StringGrid looks like:
["Корни Х" - "Roots X"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDkts.png)

When you click on the "Расчёт" (calculate) button, the answers are different, and after repeated clicking, the "Floating point overflow" error appears.

Comment: Someone has to debug this. It really should be you. But if you want somebody else to, then provide a [mcve]. Including the input data. We don't want to have to type input data to run the program. It will take you a bit of time to prepare this, but that's fine.

Comment: "Floating point overflow" means one number gets too high to be stored in `Real` - you could try using `Double` or `Extended` as type. Do you actually mean [Gauß-Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Seidel_method)?

Comment: Looking elsewhere on the internet for Seidel implementation, I can find code in various languages but those implementation looks more complex than yours. I suspect you simplified the code.

Comment: @AmigoJack: In (modern) Delphi, [`Real`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Real_Types) is the same thing as `Double` and `Extended` only exists in 32-bit applications. (But it isn't clear if the OP actually is using Delphi, since the Delphi tag sometimes is used by non-Delphi developers to get the attention of the Pascal/Delphi experts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes are

- using no comments
- using more than 2 single-letter variable names
- using anti-patterns: a counting loop (`for` loop) should be used only if you *can* predict the *exact* number of iterations. `Break` does/should not belong to your standard repertoire, I even consider it a variant of [spaghetti code](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Special:PermaLink/141142#Collatz_conjecture). There are very few [exception](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Special:PermaLink/141142#Collatz_conjecture)s to this rule, but here you it’s better to stick to using a conditional loop (`while … do` or `repeat … until`).
- omitting `begin … end` frames (for branches and loops) *during* development, when your program evidently is not finished yet

To be fair, the Seidel method *can* be confusing. On the other hand, Pascal is, provided a sufficient language proficiency, pretty well-suited for such a task.

I actually had to program that task myself in order to possibly understand why your `procedure` does not produce the right result. The following `program` uses some Extended Pascal (ISO 10206) features like schemata and type inquiries. You will need an EP-compliant compiler for that, such as the GPC (GNU Pascal Compiler). AFAIK, Delphi does not support those features, but it should be an easy task to resolve any deficiencies.

Considering all aforementioned “mistakes” you arrive at the following solution.

```
program seidel(output);

type
    naturalNumber = 1..maxInt value 1;
```

All `naturalNumber` values below are initialized with `1` unless otherwise specified. This is an EP extension.

```
    linearSystem(
            coefficientCount: naturalNumber;
            equationCount: naturalNumber
        ) = record
            coefficient: array[1..equationCount, 1..coefficientCount] of real;
            result: array[1..coefficientCount] of real;
            solution: array[1..equationCount] of real;
        end;
```

Of course you may structure that data type differently depending on your main usage scenario.

```
{
    Approximates the solution of the passed linearSystem
    using the Gauss-Seidel method.
    
    system.solution should contain an estimate of the/a solution.
}
procedure approximateSolution(var system: linearSystem);
    { Returns `true` if any element along the main diagonal is zero. }
    { NB: There is a chance of false negatives. }
    function mainDiagonalNonZero: Boolean;
    var
        product: real value 1.0;
        n: naturalNumber;
    begin
        { Take the product of all elements along the main diagonal. }
        { If any element is zero, the entire product is zero. }
        for n := 1 to system.coefficientCount do
        begin
            product := product * system.coefficient[n, n];
        end;
        
        mainDiagonalNonZero := product <> 0.0;
    end;
```

This function `mainDiagonalNonZero` serves as a reminder that you *can* “nest” routines in routines. Although it is only called once below, it cleans up your source code a bit if you structure units of code like that.

```
type
    { This is more readable than using plain integer values. }
    relativeOrder = (previous, next);
var
    approximation: array[relativeOrder] of type of system.solution;
```

Note, that `approximation` is declared in front of `getNextApproximationResidual`, so both this function and the main block of `approximateSolution` can access *the* *same* vectors.

```
    { Calculates the next approximation vector. }
    function getNextApproximationResidual: real;
    var
        { used for both, identifying the equation and a coefficient }
        n: naturalNumber;
        { used for identifying one term, i.e. coefficient × solution }
        term: 0..maxInt;
        { denotes a current error of this new/next approximation }
        residual: real;
        { denotes the largest error }
        residualMaximum: real value 0.0;
        { for simplicity, you could use `approximation[next, n]` instead }
        sum: real;
    begin
        for n := 1 to system.equationCount do
        begin
            sum := 0.0;
            
            for term := 1 to n - 1 do
            begin
                sum := sum + system.coefficient[n, term] * approximation[next, term];
            end;
            
            { term = n is skipped, because that's what we're calculating }
            
            for term := n + 1 to system.equationCount do
            begin
                sum := sum + system.coefficient[n, term] * approximation[previous, term];
            end;
```

Here it becomes apparent, that your implementation does not contain *two* `for` loops. It does not iterate over all terms.

```
            sum := system.result[n] - sum;
            { everything times the reciprocal of coefficient[n, n] }
            approximation[next, n] := sum / system.coefficient[n, n];
            
            { finally, check for larger error }
            residual := abs(approximation[next, n] - approximation[previous, n]);
            if residual > residualMaximum then
            begin
                residualMaximum := residual;
            end;
        end;
        
        getNextApproximationResidual := residualMaximum;
    end;
```

I have outsourced this function `getNextApproximationResidual` so I could write a nicer abort condition in the loop below.

```
const
    { Perform at most this many approximations before giving up. }
    limit = 1337;
    { If the approximation improved less than this value, }
    { we consider the approximation satisfactory enough. }
    errorThreshold = 8 * epsReal;
var
    iteration: naturalNumber;
begin
    if system.coefficientCount <> system.equationCount then
    begin
        writeLn('Error: Gauss-Seidel method only works  ',
            'on a _square_ system of linear equations.');
        halt;
    end;
    
    { Values in the main diagonal later appear as divisors, }
    { that means they must be non-zero. }
    if not mainDiagonalNonZero then
    begin
        writeLn('Error: supplied linear system contains ',
            'at least one zero along main diagonal.');
        halt;
    end;
```

Do *not* *trust* user input. Before we calculate anything, ensure the `system` meets some basic requirements. `halt` (without any parameters) is an EP extension. Some compilers’ `halt` also accept an `integer` parameter to communicate the error condition to the OS.

```
    { Take system.solution as a first approximation. }
    approximation[next] := system.solution;
    
    repeat
    begin
        iteration := iteration + 1;
        { approximation[next] is overwritten by `getNextApproximationError` }
        approximation[previous] := approximation[next];
    end
    until (getNextApproximationResidual < errorThreshold) or_else (iteration >= limit);
```

The `or_else` operator is an EP extension. It explicitly denotes “lazy/short-cut evaluation”. Here it wasn’t necessary, but I like it nevertheless.

```
    { Emit a warning if the previous loop terminated }
    { because of reaching the maximum number of iterations. }
    if iteration >= limit then
    begin
        writeLn('Note: Maximum number of iterations reached. ',
            'Approximation may be significantly off, ',
            'or it does not converge.');
    end;
    
    { Finally copy back our best approximation. }
    system.solution := approximation[next];
end;
```

I used the following for testing purposes. `protected` (EP) corresponds to `const` in Delphi (I guess).

```
{ Suitable for printing a small linear system. }
procedure print(protected system: linearSystem);
const
    totalWidth = 8;
    fractionWidth = 3;
    times = ' × ';
    plus = ' + ';
var
    equation, term: naturalNumber;
begin
    for equation := 1 to system.equationCount do
    begin
        write(system.coefficient[equation, 1]:totalWidth:fractionWidth,
            times,
            system.solution[1]:totalWidth:fractionWidth);
        for term := 2 to system.coefficientCount do
        begin
            write(plus,
                system.coefficient[equation, term]:totalWidth:fractionWidth,
                times,
                system.solution[term]:totalWidth:fractionWidth);
        end;
        
        writeLn('⩰  ':8, system.result[equation]:totalWidth:fractionWidth);
    end;
end;
```

The following example system of linear equations was taken [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:PermaLink/1030899964#Examples), so I “knew” the correct result:

```
{ === MAIN ============================================================= }
var
    example: linearSystem(2, 2);
begin
    with example do
    begin
        { first equation }
        coefficient[1, 1] :=  16.0;
        coefficient[1, 2] :=   3.0;
        result[1] := 11.0;
        
        { second equation }
        coefficient[2, 1] :=   7.0;
        coefficient[2, 2] := -11.0;
        result[2] := 13.0;
        
        { used as an estimate }
        solution[1] := 1.0;
        solution[2] := 1.0;
    end;
    
    approximateSolution(example);
    
    print(example);
end.
```